# How to parse this JSON wit Qt an C++?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a json like this:

```
{
  "name1": {
    "path": "D:/myfolder"
  },
  "name2": {
    "path": "D:/anotherFolder"
  },
  "name3": {
    "path": "D:/myfolder"
  }
}
```

And I want to get: are the names and the folder names. 
like :

```
   name1, D:/myfolder
   name2, D:/anotherFolder
   name3, D:/myfolder
```

It is not important if i get them independently or in an map, because i want to save them
to new variables into another  struct.
what I have so far is:

```
QString jsonFile = "myjson.json";
QFile loadFile(jsonFile);

if(!loadFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
qDebug() << "Failed to open " << loadFile;    }

QByteArray data = loadFile.readAll();
QJsonDocument loadDoc(QJsonDocument::fromJson(data));

QJsonObject json = loadDoc.object(); 
QStringList keys = json.keys();      // <------- that give me the names. check.
```

But i didnt get it: how to get the second element?!?
the nearest approche so far was to get the "2nd dimension" with foreach:

```
foreach(const QJsonValue path, json ){
        qInfo() << path;
}
```

this gave me as output:

```
QJsonValue(object, QJsonObject({"path": "D:/myfolder"}))
QJsonValue(object, QJsonObject({"path": "D:/anotherFolder"}))
QJsonValue(object, QJsonObject({"path": "D:/myfolder"}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most optimal way to do it just using single **for** iteration

```
QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data);
QJsonObject json = doc.object();
for (auto it = json.constBegin(); it != json.constEnd(); ++it)
{
    qInfo() << it.key() << it.value().toObject().value("path").toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through the keys obtaining the value, and then access the last one using the key "path":

```cpp
QJsonDocument loadDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data);
QJsonObject json = loadDoc.object();
for(const QString & key : json.keys()){
    qInfo() << key << json[key].toObject()["path"].toString();
}
```